# How to create a JTable that converts URLs into hyperlinks as you type, in Java

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jtable, jtextpane

I need a JTable that has multilined cells, and converts multiple (in one cell) URLs into clickable hyperlinks and supports basic style manipulation (bold, italic, underline), which means I can edit the style during or after entering the text. I also need it to be able to save the styled cell content into database.
What is the easiest way to achieve this?

I already tried creating a custom cell editor (and sorted out the multiline issue), which uses JTextPane and added key listener to it that listens when "space" character is released and if the last word starts with "http://", removes it from it's document and adds it again as styled text with href attribute and blue color. I also added listeners which listen for mouse clicks on hyperlinks. It all works during edit, but when the cell loses focus all text becomes unstyled and black. Maybe because I'm using different renderer and editor, but I add the key listeners to the renderer also.
I'm also having huge problems saving and especially setting table cell values when closing and starting the app. Should I go on and try to get it to work this way, or should I go back and take a different approach, like maybe setting JTextPane's content type to "text/html". If I did this I don't really know how I'll convert URLs into hyperlinks as you type.

BTW, the editor extends AbstractCellEdit, while the renderer extends JTextPane.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Robin answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12980807/572834) you on the `JTable` part, and I will add about text.

If you don't need real HTML, i.e. with links like `<a href="http://example.com">link text</a>`, then you can use `DefaultStyledDocument` as the model for your cell. To make http-prefixed text appear as a link, set the color to blue and add underline attribute. (`DefaultStyledDocument` model is simpler than `HTMLDocument`.)

To preserve formatting, you should store `Document`, the text model in Swing, for each cell.

There's no need to remove and re-insert the text to add styling. You can apply styling to the text already in the Document, use [`setCharacterAttributes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultStyledDocument.html#setCharacterAttributes%28int,%20int,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet,%20boolean%29) method.

And you can actually re-use the rendering engine of Swing text components to render your cells. You can fetch the root view for presentation using [`TextUI.getRootView()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/TextUI.html#getRootView%28javax.swing.text.JTextComponent%29). The view hierarchy can render your text and help you translate mouse clicks into text `Element`s, which you can use to launch hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks, but, wouldn't storing just the TableModel do it, instead of having to go through each cell and storing Document? I don't need real HTML, and I'm not sure how I can use DefaultStyledDocument for that matter.

Comment: Of course, you pass `TableModel` to the `JTable`, and each cell in the `TableModel` is an `Object`. The `DefaultTableModel` operates on rather simple objects, and displays the data using `toString()`. If you need the cell to display the styled text, then you have to store it somehow, preserving formatting. I don't know how you implement your `TableModel`, however, I might think after editing the text in `JEditorPane`, all the formatting is discarded and the plain text, `JEditorPane.getText()`, is stored in the table model.

Comment: That's weird, but, I tried using the same extended AbstractCellEditor to implement TableCellEditor and TableCellRenderer (class test extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer), and when focus is lost formatting is still kept, and links are clickable. Unfortunately I can't use this renderer for my table, because it somehow resizes the whole frame instead of just the cell. Maybe it only appears to have lost focus(?), becacause when I press escape key it gets grayout and discards changes. And text doesn't get wraped until I hit escape.

Comment: It appears that the focus is not lost and you still see the editor. Can you start editing another cell? It should move the focus, and you would see the formatting is lost.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the focus is not lost when I click elsewhere, but when I edit another cell. Formatting is completely lost, links are not clickable and the cell is grayed out. I need help here, i don't want this. How do I render cells?

Comment: So, the questions narrow down to, how to render styled/formatted text and how to save it (by saving only the table model or saving each cell's doocument, which I'm not sure I can get from the table reference).

Comment: As I said, you have to keep `Document` object, i.e. `DefaultStyledDocument` as the cell object in your `TableModel`. It is Serializable and will preserve all the formatting. So you have to copy the document contents from your Editor to the table model. Alternatively you can `setDocument` of your `JEditorPane` for editing when cell editor is activated. Once again: your `TableModel` should contain `Document` objects.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18333/discussion-between-alexey-ivanov-and-igor)

Answer (score 2):

- In your approach you will need a custom renderer as well. Once you stop editing, it is the renderer which takes over so the renderer has to support the same styling options as your editor
- Clickable hyperlinks in your table will not be straightforward. The renderer component is not part of the `JTable`, it is only used as stamp. As a result, all the regular things like `MouseListener`, `ActionListener`, `FocusListener`, ... which you attach to the component are never triggered as the component is not part of the Swing hierarchy. If I remember correctly SwingX has built-in support for hyperlinks in `JTable`s but not sure they can be combined with a styled HTML document
- When your editor extends `JTextPane` use a `DocumentListener` instead of a `KeyListener`
- Saving/loading is basically just dumping your `TableModel` to a persistent state and back. This looks like the easy part of the requirement

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I have a renderer too. But it doesn't seem to get the styling of the text from the editor, once the cell loses focus. I'm using keylistener instead of document listener because I don't need to listen to changes everytime a key is pressed, but everytime space or return is released.
I'll look into SwingX, maybe it's easier there.
Thanks for pointing out I should use TableModel to save table content. I should have thought of it before i wasted my time creating loops that save content cell by cell. btw, should I convert the TableModel into XMLbefore saving?